# How do I write this more general version of `Control.Monad.Writer.censor`?

Tags: haskell, monads

The standard `Control.Monad.Writer.censor` is dual to the standard
`Control.Monad.Reader.local`, with `censor` modifying the writer state
*after* the computation and `local` modifying the reader state
*before* the computation:

```
censor :: (w -> w) -> Writer w a -> Writer w a
local  :: (r -> r) -> Reader r a -> Reader r a
```

However, the `Reader` and `Writer` monads are not entirely
symmetric. Namely, a writer computation produces a *result*, in
addition to a writer state, and I'm trying to write an alternative
version of `censor` that takes advantage of this asymmetry.  I want to
write a function

```
censorWithResult :: (a -> w -> w) -> Writer w a -> Writer w a
```

which takes a transformer of type `a -> w -> w` that receives the
result of the computation *in addition* to the writer state.  I don't
see how to write this function using `tell`, `listen`, and `pass`.

The precise behavior I expect of `censorWithResult` is that if

```
ma :: Writer w a
f  :: a -> w -> w
```

and

```
runWriter ma = (r , y)
```

then

```
runWriter (censorWithResult f ma) = (r , f r y)
```

whereas

```
runWriter (censor g ma) = (r , g y)
```

when `g :: w -> w`.

## Example

This shouldn't be necessary to understand the question, but here's a
simplified version of the motivating example:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Writer

-- Call-trace data type for functions from 'Int' to 'Int'.
--
-- A 'Call x subs r' is for a call with argument 'x', sub calls
-- 'subs', and result 'r'.
data Trace = Call Int Forest Int
type Forest = [Trace]

-- A writer monad for capturing call traces.
type M a = Writer Forest a

-- Recursive traced negation function.
--
-- E.g. we expect that
--
--   runWriter (t 2) = (-2 , Call 2 [Call 1 [Call 0 [] 0] -1] -2)
t , n :: Int -> M Int
t x = trace n x
n x = if x <= 0 then pure 0 else subtract 1 <$> t (x - 1)

trace :: (Int -> M Int) -> (Int -> M Int)
trace h x = do
  censorWithResult (\r subs -> [Call x subs r]) (h x)

-- The idea is that if 'ma :: Writer w a' and 'runWriter ma = (r , y)'
-- then 'runWriter (censorWithResult f ma) = (r , f r y)'. I.e.,
-- 'censorWithResult' is like 'Control.Monad.Writer.censor', except it
-- has access to the result of the 'Writer' computation, in addition
-- to the written data.
censorWithResult :: (a -> w -> w) -> Writer w a -> Writer w a
censorWithResult = undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are allowed to use only `tell`, `pass` and `listen`, the only function that is able to access output is

```
-- | `pass m` is an action that executes the action `m`, which returns a value
-- and a function, and returns the value, applying the function to the output. 
pass :: (MonadWriter w m) => m (a, w -> w) -> m a
```

So for `censorWithResult`, we need to partially apply a given function of type `a -> w -> w` to get `w -> w` and handle it to `pass`. This can be accomplished as

```
censorWithResult :: (MonadWriter w m) => (a -> w -> w) -> m a -> m a
censorWithResult f m = pass $ do
    a <- m
    return (a, f a)
```

The action inside `pass` executes the given action, partially applies `f` to it and `pass` then modifies the output accordingly.

Answer (score 21):

> The precise behavior I expect of `censorWithResult` is that if
>
> ```
> ma :: Writer w a
> f  :: a -> w -> w
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> runWriter ma = (r , y)
> ```
>
> then
>
> ```
> runWriter (censorWithResult f ma) = (r , f r y)
> ```

Okay, let's do that, then. The only thing you need to know is that `writer` is a left inverse for `runWriter`. Then we get the following chain of equalities, first by appling `writer` to both sides, then by eliminating the left inverse.

```
        runWriter (censorWithResult f ma)  =        (r, f r y)
writer (runWriter (censorWithResult f ma)) = writer (r, f r y)
                   censorWithResult f ma   = writer (r, f r y)
```

The only thing we need to do now is plug in your equation `runWriter ma = (r, y)`:

```
censorWithResult f ma = let (r, y) = runWriter ma in writer (r, f r y)
```

Ain't equational reasoning grand?

Comment: Way to think outside the monad :D